# Node JS Sync check if file is being uploaded

Tags: node.js, ftp, synchronization

I need to check if a file is being uploaded to a FTP server. I have no control over the server side (I'd just love a file.temp rename), so my option (best guess to my knowledge of FTP) is to ask the file size or last modified after an interval. My problem is I would need this to be sync.

```
function isStillUploading(ftp, filePath) {
  var startFileSize = -1;
  var nextFileSize = -2;

  ftp.size(filePath,
           function sizeReturned(error, size) {
             if (!error) startFileSize = size;
             else startFileSize = -3;
           });

  // CPU-melting style delay.
  var start = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - start < 500) { }

  ftp.size(filePath,
           function sizeReturned(error, size) {
             if (!error) nextFileSize = size;
             else nextFileSize = -4;
           });

  // This would be better, but I have no way of having 
  // root f wait for this and return a correct boolean.
  //setTimeout(ftp.size(filePath,
  //                    function sizeReturned(error, size) {
  //                      if (!error) nextFileSize = size;
  //                      else nextFileSize = -4;
  //                    }),
  //            500);

  // TODO: add checks for -1 -2 -3 -4
  console.log("File size change: " + startFileSize + ":" + nextFileSize);
  return (startFileSize != nextFileSize);
}
```

Writing this in a callback style would still imply a loop somewhere to re-check the file's size or (IMO) nasty callback nesting I really don't like. As far as code readability goes, I think just making it sync would be so much easier.

Is there a simple way of doing this or should I re-write with callbacks and events?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Reconsider your application. Sleeping on a master thread is simply *MUST-NOT*.

Comment: I know, that's why I ask. The thing is, sometimes you just have to wait! Otherwise you risk starting 10000 simultaneous downloads, or processing files before you finished mapping the subfolders. For example, I use recursivity, but how do I know I reached the end of my folder tree before starting downloads? (nothing to do with OP but another of my problems and more related to the nature or JS)

Comment: It is a perception of one's mind as well :) Start thinking asynchronously, and the code will flow. It is not an easy task, especially if you have experience in other programming languages. I advice a book..   The key idea is not to wait until folders are indexed, but to start WHEN folders are indexed. That is what callback is for :)